# PS: Remove Azure NIC from LB Pool

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-load-balancer

I'm trying to remove Azure Load Balancer Backend Pool setting out of NIC Ipconfig in PowerShell but not succeeding without destroying whole Ipconfig. Either it removes entire config like

```
Remove-AzNetworkInterfaceIpConfig -NetworkInterface $NIC
```

Or when I was trying to set Ipconfig while naming other properties, LB pool config persists

`Set-AzNetworkInterfaceIpConfig -NetworkInterface $NIC -Name "ipconfig1" -PrivateIpAddress $DIP -Subnet $backendSubnet -PublicIpAddress $PIP -ApplicationSecurityGroup` $NSG

How can I only remove LB Backend Pool and keep the other properties? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want just remove or add specific NIC you can use this one. Just pass required variables and Action name "remove" or "add". It removes only NIC from Backend Load Balancer Pool, but didn't destroys whole Backend Pool configuration.

```bsh
$ResourceGroup = "YourResourceGroupName"
$Loadbalancer = "YourLoadBalancerName"
$NICName = "YourVirtualMachineNetworkInterfaceName"
$Action = "remove" #add

if ($Action -eq 'add')
{
    Write-Host ("Adding to LB")

    $nic = Get-AzNetworkInterface | Where-Object { ($_.ResourceGroupName -eq "$ResourceGroup") -and ($_.Name -eq "$NICName") }
    $lb = Get-AzLoadBalancer | Where-Object { ($_.ResourceGroupName -eq "$ResourceGroup") -and ($_.Name -eq "$Loadbalancer") }
    $nic.IpConfigurations[0].LoadBalancerBackendAddressPools = $lb.BackendAddressPools[0]
    Set-AzNetworkInterface -NetworkInterface $nic
}
if ($Action -eq 'remove')
{
    Write-Host ("Removing from LB")

    $nic = Get-AzNetworkInterface | Where-Object { ($_.ResourceGroupName -eq "$ResourceGroup") -and ($_.Name -eq "$NICName") }
    $nic.Ipconfigurations[0].LoadBalancerBackendAddressPools = $null
    Set-AzNetworkInterface -NetworkInterface $nic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is not remove the Ipconfig of the NIC, but remove the nat rule config and backend pool config from the Load Balancer that associated with the Ipconfig of the NIC. And the example code here:

```
$resourceGrouName = "xxxxx"
$loabBalancerName = "xxxxx"
$inboundRuleConfigName = "xxxxx"
$backendpoolconfigName = "xxxxx"
$lb = Get-AzLoadBalancer -ResourceGroupName $resourceGrouName -Name $loabBalancerName
Remove-AzLoadBalancerInboundNatRuleConfig -LoadBalancer $lb -Name $inboundRuleConfigName
Remove-AzLoadBalancerBackendAddressPoolConfig -LoadBalancer $lb -Name $backendpoolconfigName
Set-AzLoadBalancer -LoadBalancer $lb
```

And you need to change the variables into yours. Then you can find the info about the Load Balancer that was removed from the Ipconfig of the NIC.

Comment: that removes whole backend pool. If I want to remove or add just one NIC, do I have to always remove and create entire backend pool?

Comment: @rokmatr As I know, when you create the backend pool with single VM, then the backend pool can only contain the only one VM. So when you remove the Ipconfig of the VM, you need to remove the whole backend pool.

Comment: @rokmatr Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If yes and you do not mind, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: thanks for assistance but it turns that you don't have to remove entire backend pool config but just modify NIC Ipconfig. I've tried 

$DeactivateNIC = Get-AzNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $RG -Name $DeactivateNICName
        
$DeactivateNIC.IpConfigurations[0].LoadBalancerBackendAddressPools = $null

Set-AzNetworkInterface -NetworkInterface $DeactivateNIC

that works and LB pool stays. For adding I just use a LB pool name in the Ipconfig property

Comment: @rokmatr That's not the recommended action. But that's no problem if you think it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

turns that you don't have to remove entire backend pool config but just modify NIC Ipconfig. I've tried

```
$DeactivateNIC = Get-AzNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $RG -Name $DeactivateNICName 
$DeactivateNIC.IpConfigurations[0].LoadBalancerBackendAddressPools = $null 
Set-AzNetworkInterface -NetworkInterface $DeactivateNIC
```

that works and LB pool stays. For adding I just add the Ipconfig property like:

$ActivateNIC = Get-AzNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $RG -Name $ActivateNICName

```
    $lb = Get-AzLoadBalancer -ResourceGroupName $RG -Name "LB"
    $lbPoolConfig = Get-AzLoadBalancerBackendAddressPoolConfig -LoadBalancer $lb 

    $ActivateNIC.IpConfigurations[0].LoadBalancerBackendAddressPools=$lbPoolConfig
    Set-AzNetworkInterface -NetworkInterface $ActivateNIC
```

Answer (score 0):

#Connect-AzAccount -Subscription "My-Paid-Subscription" -TenantId 50a3f5a3-eb4b-491c-9e92-1a059bf391d4
$Action = Read-Host("Select remove/add")

$ResourceGroup = Read-Host("YourResourceGroupName")

$Loadbalancer = Read-Host("YourLoadBalancerName")

$NICName = Read-Host("YourVirtualMachineNetworkInterfaceName")

$IP = Read-Host ("Please enter the IP address of the backend")

if ($Action -eq 'add')
{
$BackendPool = Read-Host("Enter backend pool name")

```
    Write-Host ("Adding to the Load Balancer") -ForegroundColor Yellow

    $nic = Get-AzNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Name $NICName
    $lb = Get-AzLoadBalancer -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Name $Loadbalancer
    try{
        foreach($ipconf in $nic.Ipconfigurations)
        {
            if ($ipconf.PrivateIpAddress -eq $IP){
                foreach($backend in $lb.BackendAddressPools){
                    if ($backend.Name -eq $BackendPool){
                    $ipconf.LoadBalancerBackendAddressPools = $backend
                    Set-AzNetworkInterface -NetworkInterface $nic
                    Write-Host "Successfully added the backend to the Load balancer" -ForegroundColor Green

                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
        }
    catch{
        Write-Host "Error Occured during addition" -ForegroundColor Red
        }

}
if ($Action -eq 'remove')
{
    Write-Host ("Removing from the Load balancer") -ForegroundColor Yellow

    $nic = Get-AzNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Name $NICName
    try{
        foreach($ipconf in $nic.Ipconfigurations)
        {
            if ($ipconf.PrivateIpAddress -eq $IP){
                $ipconf.LoadBalancerBackendAddressPools = $null
                Set-AzNetworkInterface -NetworkInterface $nic
                Write-Host "Successfully removed the backend from the Load balancer" -ForegroundColor Green
            }
        }
        }
    catch{
        Write-Host "Error Occured during removal" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    
    
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).